# plotting a generated contour on a particular portion of the image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, contour

I have a problem regarding Image Processing in matlab.

I have an image :

[image: Original Image]

It has a large size. I select a portion of the image . The selection portion of the image is between the range (Xmin:Xmax,Ymin:Ymax) of the Image array. Then I do some operation on that selected portion of the image array and generate a contour map. What I want to do now is to remap this contour on my original Image. I do have all the set of coordinates required.

The generated contour is shown as well as the selected area of the image.
[image: Contour Generated]
[image: Selected Area of the Image]

Please tell me how I can do this in MATLAB. The expected output is also shown below . Please note that I have done this in paint so the figure might not be clear.

[image: Final Result]

Thanks in advance guys!!

I hope I have made my question clear. For further clarification do comment guys. And I am sorry for my pretty bad editing.... I am complete novice at this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need just an idea or a code to be able to do what you want.

My idea would be the following:
1) Merge the two images (raw image and outline); the outline pixels should have a value which is a little bit higher than the highest grayscale value in the raw image.
2) Plot this merged image
3) Adjust the colormap. To do this manually, you can go to the menu of a plotted figure -> edit -> colormap ... -> then change the color of the highest value.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. But as you can see My original Image is a gray-scale one whereas the contour has to be plotted in some colour preferably blue. So how can I merge a gray-scale image with a colour one ?

Comment: @roni My idea was like this:

    picture = rand(200); picture(100:200,30:34) = 2;
    A = colormap(gray); A(end,:) = [1 1 0];
    figure('Colormap',A); imagesc(picture)

Do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

use the technique of snake2D algorithm with iterations of '0' then you will get the selected output on the image itself.

But i dont know how to crop it into seperate image